# Possible to Kotlin extend/override Double.toString to produce less decimal places?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I already have a hack:

```kotlin
/** Shorter round for the logs */
val Double.str: String
    get() = "%.3f".format(this)
```

But that has to be manually inserted into all of my `LOG.info { "It went ${distance.str}" }` statements.  I'd prefer to be able to set the (float and decimal) significant digits globally.  Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do so. Instead, you could redefine your `LOG` methods, but they'll likely need to take parts as separate parameters (i.e. `LOG.info("It went {}", distance)` or `LOG.info { myformat("It went {}", distance) }`). You'd need to decide if that's a trade-off you want.

The only way I can see for `LOG.info { "It went ${distance}" }` to work is to find numbers in the interpolated string using regular expressions and replace them. Which is a pretty ugly hack and relatively slow.

Answer (score 0):

Seems class extension function will help:

```
fun Double.str(decPlaces: Int): String = "%.${decPlaces}f".format(this)
```

and use it like

```
LOG.info { "It went ${distance.str(3)}" }
```

Comment: His problem is that he doesn't want to repeat `.str` and your answer suggests repeating `.str(3)` instead.